# Enquiry about an error in AndroId Studio

Tags: android

I can't create a new app on `Android Studio` . When I attempt to create a new app it appears error that includes the following :"your android SDK is missing ,out of Date ,or is missing templates you can configure your SDK via configure-project structure-SDKS " 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Sounds like Android Studio needs updated or possibly reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by doing what it tells you to do

> you can configure your SDK via configure-project structure-SDKS

Comment: configure from any menu ?

Comment: When you first open Android Studio, it gives you a list of projects in the left, or the option to create a new project on the right. Towards the bottom of that window is a settings button.